# How to see live changes on an Angular project?

Tags: angular

I'm running an Angular project using the command line: "ng serve". When I use Ionic, I just run ionic serve and the updates I perform on the code, can be seen live on the browser, how can I do the same things on Angular?

Comment: [`ng serve`](https://angular.io/cli/serve) should do the job: _Builds and serves your app, rebuilding on file changes._

Answer (score 1):

You mean that you want open automatically the browser on ng serve? Just put `--open` after it. The complete code is follow:

`ng serve --open`